# Can't get my head around enumitem's spacing parameters

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

Maybe it's my terrible lack of sleep but I can't get my head around `enumitem`'s horizontal spacing parameters.

What I want is a description environment in which the first line of each item (where the item title is) is aligned to same left-margin as the the surrounding text and all lines below it are indented by the "normal" amount.

For example:

```
Some test

**Some Item** item description
   continues here on indented line

**Another Item** item description
   continues here on indented line
```

Can anyone show me how to get this result with `enumitem`'s 5-10 spacing parameters (`labelmargin`, `itemindent`, `labelsep`, `labelwidth`, `labelindent`, ...)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip} %to disable paragraph indentation but still keep paragraphs separated (with \parskip)
\setlength{\parskip}{2.75ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}%[WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?]
\item Some Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long

\item Another Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

With this code the "item titles" are slightly indented, which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps some explanation of what's going would be helpful. [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was used to highlight the text block boundaries, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style.

Consider the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{lipsum}  % http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}
\item Some Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long

\item Another Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

You notice the gap between the left margin and the first heading. This is because `\item` in the `description` environment actually typesets a label "heading" in **bold**. This `<heading>` is given by the optional argument to `\item[<heading>]`. If you specify *nothing* (no optional argument), the *regular* gap between the "heading" and the "item body" (or the length `\labelsep`) is inserted. To remove this, you could use

[image]

```
% similar to the above MWE
\begin{description}
\item \hskip-\labelsep Some Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long

\item Another Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long
\end{description}
% similar to the above MWE
```

This, however, defeats the purpose of an itemized list (which `description` is), since there is no "item" or "heading". Another way to obtain the formatting you're after, is to use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and format an `itemize` environment *without* any label:

[image]

```
% similar to the above MWE
\begin{itemize}[label=,itemindent=-2.5em,leftmargin=2.5em]
\item Some Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long

\item Another Item: item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long
\end{itemize}
% similar to the above MWE
```

This indents the entire `itemize` environment by `2.5em` (given by `leftmargin`), "undents" only the `itemindent` (the first line indent) by the same amount, and typeset no label (`label=`).

However, if your main aim is to remove the typesetting from the item heading itself, rather format it using `enumitem` and use the structure that the list was intended for:

[image]

```
% similar to the above MWE
\begin{description}[format=\normalfont]
\item[Some Item:] item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long

\item[Another Item:] item description
   continues here on indented line
   when the description is long
\end{description}
% similar to the above MWE
```

Comment: +1 great! By this explanation you solved my `enumitem`-problem, too! Thank!

Answer (score 7):

I seem to get the behavior you describe without adjusting **any** parameters:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `[showframe]` option was used with the `geometry` package to see the frame.
- The `lipsum` package was used to provide dummy text.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [Lipsum 1] \lipsum[1]

\item [Lipsum 2] \lipsum[2]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nope, put some text above it and you will see that the item titles are slightly indented.

Comment: I added a MWE in my question, based on your code.

Comment: Have updated the MWE, and also correctly used `[]` to specify the item title and you can see that there is no indentation.