# Shaded continuous across new enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate, framed, shading

I'm trying to write up solutions where I include the original problem text, in a light gray shaded box.  I had been creating the shading with the 'framed' package `shaded` environment, but some of the problems have enumerated parts, with some text before the parts.  I would like to have the starting text and the first part continuously shaded, but apparently the `shaded` environment can't cross a `\begin{enumerate}`.  So what I have right now is

```
\begin{shaded}Starting text...\end{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{shaded}\item This is the first problem.\end{shaded}
This is the first solution.
\begin{shaded}\item This is the second problem.\end{shaded}
Second solution.
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a way to have the shading continuous instead of that first gap?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Basic Solution:

I would recommend that you use [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) instead (as it will work across page breaks), and use the `resume*` option with lists via [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/):

[image]

---

### Better Solution:

As @MarcoDaniel suggested, a better looking solution is to use the `frametitle` option with `mdframed`.

```
\newenvironment{Question}[1]{
    \begin{mdframed}[
       frametitle={#1},
       frametitlerule=true,
       frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!20,
       frametitlebelowskip=2pt,
       innerlinewidth=1.0pt
    ]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}
```

With this you simply enclose the part you wanted shaded in the first parameter to the `Question` environment, and the body of this environment is the answer, i.e., the part you don't wanted shaded. This yields:

[image]

- For some reason there is a display issue with this. There are lines at the top and bottom but with increasing magnification from `150%` and incrementing by `1%` with Acrobat Reader 10.1.2 on Mac different lines appear and disappear.  I have updated this to use `framemthod=tikz` and `innerlinewidth=1.0pt` option as this make this display problem less noticeable (but problem is still there).

---

### Even Better Solution (Custom Counter):

If you are only using the `enumerate` to create a numbered list, you could simplify things even further by using a custom counter.  This is also courtesy of @MarcoDaniel.

[image]

### Notes:

- If you are not already using `enumitem`, you should have a look at:

  [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)

  [Suggestions for transitioning from paralist to enumitem package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21650/suggestions-for-transitioning-from-paralist-to-enumitem-package)
- If you happen to be using this within minipages, please do make a note of [Resuming a list started within a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21596/resuming-a-list-started-within-a-minipage)
- To adjust the settings of `enumitem`, refer to 
  [Can't get my head around enumitem's spacing parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38850/cant-get-my-head-around-enumitems-spacing-parameters)

---

### Code: Basic Solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=yellow]{shaded}

\begin{document}
\begin{shaded}
    Starting text...
    \begin{enumerate}[series=MyQuestions,leftmargin=*]
    \item This is the first problem.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyQuestions]
\item[] This is the first solution (not shaded)
\end{enumerate}
%
\begin{shaded}
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyQuestions]
    \item This is the second problem.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{shaded}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyQuestions]
\item[] Second solution (not shaded)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Better Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newenvironment{Question}[1]{
    \begin{mdframed}[
        frametitle={#1},
        frametitlerule=true,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=red!20,
        frametitlebelowskip=2pt,
        innerlinewidth=1.0pt
    ]
}{
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Question}{
        Starting text...
        \begin{enumerate}[series=MyQuestions,leftmargin=*]
        \item This is the first problem.
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    This is the first solution (not shaded)
\end{Question}

\bigskip
\begin{Question}{
        \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyQuestions]
        \item This is the second problem.
        \end{enumerate}
    }
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*=MyQuestions]
    \item[] Second solution (not shaded)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{Question}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Even Better Solution (Custom Counter):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{QuestionsStyle}{%
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=yellow,
    linewidth=2pt,
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
    innerleftmargin=30pt,
    frametitlebelowskip=.5\topskip,
    innertopmargin=\topskip
}
\newcounter{QuestionCounter}
\setcounter{QuestionCounter}{0}
\newrobustcmd*\SetQuestionNum{\mbox{}\llap{\stepcounter{QuestionCounter}\theQuestionCounter\hspace*{10pt}}}
\newmdenv[style=QuestionsStyle]{Question}
\begin{document}
\begin{Question}[frametitle={
    Some Text\\
    \\
    \SetQuestionNum This is the first problem.}]
This is the first solution (not shaded)
\end{Question}

\bigskip
\begin{Question}[frametitle={
    \SetQuestionNum This is the second problem.}]
Second solution (not shaded)
\end{Question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A solution by using `frametitle` seems to be possible. So you can set the `frametitlebackgroundcolor`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Excellent idea. I have replaced the earlier _Better Solution_ to use `frametitle`. However, I notice a slight display issue as I pointed out in the solution. Definitely a problem with the Acrobat display as different magnifications show different lines.

Comment: Have you recognize my example in the chat?

Comment: Hmm, I can't typeset the 'better solution', I get `frametitle undefined`.

Comment: @MicahDombrowski: You probably have an older version of `mdframed`. I think that was a recent enhancement.