# Disable automatic indenting on description items

Tags: lists, indentation, description

Here's the default functionality for `description` items:

[image]

With this code

```
\begin{description}
    \item Lorem ipsum...
\end{description}
```

Is there any way to make this flush all along the left side with no automatic indentation?

Comment: Do you still want the small indentation the item has with respect to regular paragraphs? If it's truly flush left on every line, your items will be difficult to distinguish from regular paragraphs. And even with a small indentation on all lines, there won't be much contrast. A larger example may help show where you see a problem with the regular formatting.

Comment: Note that using a `description` environment *without* any optional argument to `\item` inserts what seems to be a spurious space (`\labelsep`) between the margins (see [Can't get my head around enumitem's spacing parameters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38850/5764)). So, please describe what you're after exactly, since using the `description` environment might not be the best option available.

Comment: @Werner I'm working on my resume [here](rwell.org/resume.pdf). In the background section, I don't want the second and third lines to be indented, but rather flush with the first line. I realized I don't need to use a {description} here, should I use something else?

Comment: @CoreyFarwell: I would literally just set that paragraph on its own in a `raggedright` environment: `\begin{raggedright} I'm currently... \end{raggedright}`. That should remove the paragraph indent, but still maintain your `\raggeright` look. Give some feedback if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you load the `enumitem` package then you can tweak this option (and many others) using a `key=value` approach.

In your particular case, you can use

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=*]
```

If you want to assign this behaviour globally, you can use

```
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=*}
```

[image]

A complete MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

See the documentation for further details: `texdoc enumitem`

Comment: I compiled your code exactly as written and it still indents after the first line

Comment: @CoreyFarwell strange! I've added a screenshot showing how the code outputs for me. Perhaps I've misunderstood the question- Werner's comment sounds particularly relevant

Comment: Alright, I'll talk with Werner. But anyways, [here's the result](http://i.imgur.com/xUpOf.png)

Comment: @CoreyFarwell add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}`, it sounds like your distro is out of date

Comment: [here's the output](http://pastie.org/3460646)

Comment: @CoreyFarwell your distro is out of date- the latest enumitem is from 2011. update, re-try my code, and post back