# description without automatic indenting

Tags: description

I want to use the `description` environment, but without indenting.

```
\begin{description}
\item[Test1]\hfill \\
This is test 1
\item[Test2]\hfill \\
This is test 2
\item[Test3]\hfill \\
This is test 3
\end{description}
```

This code generates this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

i know, i could use `\textbf{}` for the headlines, but is there also a way with `description`?

Comment: Have a look at the enumerate package. No time for a full answer right now.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to have numbers before each enumerate.

Comment: And please provide, as always, a compileable code.

Comment: You could as well have a look at the following questions and their answers dealing with the removal of indentation in the description environment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119638/134144
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211466/134144
https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45823/134144

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Don't you mean `enumitem` instead of `enumerate`?

Comment: Yes. My mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code may helps you:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent\z@\leftmargin\z@
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep
                                \normalfont\bfseries #1}
\makeatother

\begin{description}
\item[Test1]\hfill \\
This is test 1
\item[Test2]\hfill \\
This is test 2
\item[Test3]\hfill \\
This is test 3
\end{description}
```

Comment: This, (together with ``adjustwidth`` for more descriptions inside descriptions) is the solution!

Answer (score 3):

Why reinvent the wheel? With `enumitem` you have all the tools needed via a system of keys:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength\parindent{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline, leftmargin=0pt, parsep=0pt, listparindent=1em, itemsep=1ex, font =\sffamily\bfseries]
  \item[Test1]
        This is test 1.

  \item[Test2]
        This is test 2.

  \item[Test3]
        This is test 3.

        A second (indented) paragraph in the description of this item.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]