# LaTex Hanging Indent Question

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, formatting, indentation, cv

I'm new to LaTex but currently trying to rewrite my resume in LaTex since its easier for formatting and version control. As of right now, it's going well except for one small problem. I can't seem to create a hanging indent in this section which I have included below:

[image]

I would like the text to be indented a couple spaces from the colon and then the next line to start at that same location. (\hangindent did not work for me) Thanks for your help!

Here is the compilable code that shows the output:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parskip}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage[bottom=0.5in,top=0.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

% Custom commands

%spacing between two bullet points
\newcommand{\resumeItemm}[2]{
  \item\small{
    #2 \vspace{-4pt}
  }
}
\newcommand{\resumeSubItemm}[2]{\resumeItemm{#1}{#2}\vspace{-3pt}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{description}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{description}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-1pt}}


\begin{document}
\section{Skills}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItemm{}
      {\textbf{\small Software: }{\small Something • Resume Thing Here • Writing Some Words • All Help is Appreciated • Thanks in Advance • I Hope This Works • Yes I Am Writing Random Words Here •  Microsoft Office Suite}}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's much more helpful to post complete minimal compilable documents that show your problem rather than code fragments as you have done. And presumably your problem can be exemplified with just a small  number of your custom commands, so we don't need to see all of them.

Comment: you're definitely right, sorry about that. I just edited it so that copying and pasting that code will compile and show what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making life unnecessarily complicated for yourself. Since you're loading the `enumitem` package, use its ability to make new lists to format your items as you desire. Then the code is much cleaner.

So I've made a new description list and given it a format which I think matches what you want.

I've also adjusted your `titlesec` commands. Vertical spacing should not be put into the `\titleformat` command; use the `\titlespacing` command. I've removed the `fullpage` package, since you're loading `geometry`, and added `\pagestyle{empty}` which is what the `empty` option of `fullpage` was doing. I've removed the `pdftex` driver option from `hyperref` and moved it to load last (which it should generally).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[]{hyperref} % generally don't specify the driver for hyperref and load it last
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage[bottom=0.5in,top=0.5in,left=0.5in,right=0.5in]{geometry}

\urlstyle{same}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1} % these values = 1ex + some stretch

% Custom lists
\newlist{resumeSubHeading}{description}{1}
\newlist{resumeItemList}{itemize}{1} % not used in this example
\setlist*[resumeSubHeading,1]{leftmargin=*,widest={MyWidestX},font=\small}
\setlist*[resumeItemList,1]{nosep,font=\small} % not used in this example


\begin{document}
\section{Skills}
\begin{resumeSubHeading}
     \item[Software:]{Something • Resume Thing Here • Writing Some Words • All Help is Appreciated • Thanks in Advance • I Hope This Works • Yes I Am Writing Random Words Here •  Microsoft Office Suite}
     \item[Other stuff:]{Something • Resume Thing Here • Writing Some Words • All Help is Appreciated • Thanks in Advance • I Hope This Works • Yes I Am Writing Random Words Here •  Microsoft Office Suite}
\end{resumeSubHeading}
\section{Skills}
\begin{resumeSubHeading}
     \item[Software:]{Something • Resume Thing Here • Writing Some Words • All Help is Appreciated • Thanks in Advance • I Hope This Works • Yes I Am Writing Random Words Here •  Microsoft Office Suite}
     \item[Other stuff:]{Something • Resume Thing Here • Writing Some Words • All Help is Appreciated • Thanks in Advance • I Hope This Works • Yes I Am Writing Random Words Here •  Microsoft Office Suite}
\end{resumeSubHeading}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

You can play around with the `enumitem` spacing parameters to change the horizontal spacing of the list.  You can find the documentation for `enumitem` [here](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem). These parameters  are quite tricky to understand fully. See [can someone please explain the enumitem horizontal spacing parameters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184780/2693) and [Can't get my head around enumitem's spacing parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38850/2693) for some discussion of how they work.  But as an example to answer the question you ask in your comment, we can use the following specification to make the list have a hanging indent.  I've also added the `before=\small` key to make both the label and the item text `\small`.

```
\setlist*[resumeSubHeading,1]{leftmargin=1cm,before=\small}
```

[image: output of modification]

Comment: this is really helpful, thank you so much for cleaning up my code and explaining that stuff!! I have two questions on this though (they might be kind of glaringly obvious questions but I'm new)... 1. how can i change the tab spacing between "Software" and "Something" and 2. how can i change the font size of the description? I see that in your setlist you changed the bolded words to \small but what about the rest of the description (assuming i don't want to change the font size at the page declaration)? Thanks so much for your patience and all your help, you're amazing!

Comment: @KipsPatel I've added another example and some pointers to explanations of the horizontal spacing parameters in `enumitem`.

Comment: just wanted to let you know that after reading up on those links and the documentation, i was finally able to get it to look the way i wanted! Thank you so much for all of your help, definitely would not have gotten this far without your guidance! You're a legend!!